# URL background session downloadTask error

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

I want to know whether completion handler blocks are supported in background sessions.

Right now, I'm getting this error:

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)
There are two ways for a session to download:

use delegate methods
use completion handlers like below.
However, when I'm using the following code I'm getting the error.

```
let session_config = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "myID");

let session = URLSession(configuration: session_config);

let task=session.downloadTask(with: request) { (url,response,error) in  
}

task.resume()
```

Comment: Can you tell me which Deployment target you are using?

Comment: my deployment target is iOS 10.3.1